# Garry's Mod Gamemode Without Weapons

Tags: mods, source-engine, garrys-mod

I have a kid who loves Minecraft and I think he would enjoy Garry's Mod in terms of building maps, contraptions and so on. However, I don't particularly want him being able to use weapons and 'mobs' in his creations.

Is it possible to create a gamemode that restricts the usage of certain classes of object ?

Comment: I love the idea of turning creation of a game into a game. Should there be ESRB/PEGI ratings for modding tools :p

Comment: I don't have a Gmod install to look at right now, but you may just be able to go in and delete those items from the files, seeing as, if I recall correctly, adding items is as easy as dropping them in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe I found something around (and your idea is awesome, actually)

In your GMOD installation you should see a folder like this: `lua/autorun/server/`

Create your LUA script (`noguns.lua`) with a text editor and paste this in:

```
function StripAndGive(ply) 
    ply:StripWeapons() 
    ply:Give("weapon_physcannon") 
    ply:Give("weapon_gravgun") 
    ply:Give("gmod_toolgun") 
    return true 
end 
hook.Add("PlayerLoadout", "StripAndGive", StripAndGive)
```

After you save the script, move it in the above folder. The source is [this thread](http://gamebanana.com/threads/134561) and it's 4 years old. So this may not be working properly (or at all) but comes with a nice [scripting guide](http://gamebanana.com/gmod/tuts/5950).

Comment: It should be noted that this could be circumvented by the kid if he deletes this file from the folder. If the parent is worried about the kid interacting with guns in a game, though, I'd assume the kid isn't old enough to be this crafty.

Comment: By reading around, it seems there's not a way to prevent by default weapons (the "adult content password" some games provide to hide gore etc) so anything the kid does could spoil the hack :) In this case, the OP needs to backup the file just in case...

Comment: @Dave if he can figure out how to circumvent that, I'll assume he's mature enough to handle more adult content. :)